# Modelling many-to-many with relation data in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two models in my application, Transaction and Person, with a many-to-many relationship. There are persons included in each Transaction. For each person, there is also a amount connected to each Transaction the Person is connected to. Therefor I need to model a many-to-many relationship with relation data. Google suggest this approach:

http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/articles/modeling.html

With this approach I have a model like this:

```
class TransactionPerson(db.Model):
    # References
    transaction = db.ReferenceProperty(Transaction, required=True)
    person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person, required=True)
    # Values
    amount = db.FloatProperty(required=True)
```

But I find that very bad for performance because if I need to summarize the amount for each Person in all Transactions I need to loop Person*Transaction*TransactionPerson times to implement the "join" while summing the amounts.

**MY IDEA**

My idea is to have two lists in the Transaction model:

```
class Transaction(db.Model):
    persons = ListProperty(db.Key)
    persons_amount = ListProperty(float)
```

This way I don't need to loop through all TransactionPerson for each Person to find the associated Transaction. And I can still query Transactions based on a Person.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is this possible? Can you trust that the list order is always the same when storing/retriving so the indexes sync between the lists?
2. Is this a good way to implement many-to-many relationship with associated data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're solving the wrong problem. The intermediate association entity is a good approach.  The problem you have is that summaries take a long time to compute;  You should be concerned more about that;

The preferred approach is to *calculate the summary data ahead of time*.

In the specific case of "Transaction totals per Person" that would mean you want to add an extra field to the Person model and update it with a running total of all of their transactions.  You would update this any time a TransactionPerson is modified, so that the summary value is always correct.

Comment: But why is en intermediate association entity a good approach when it will cause less efficient operations? For example with your approach; if a Transaction is updated I often need to update all Person objects associated with the Transaction. I don't need that if I use my approach? What are the reasons is is better to use an association entity?

Comment: Either could be the better choice for what you're doing, But My answer is focused on the specific question of calculating summary data.  If you have to load more than a handful of entities to satisfy a particular request, you probably need to find a way to extract that process out of the request and build it up in some other way, like when the value would change.

Comment: The summary data was only an example. I often want to get all persons in a Transaction which in practice results in the same Person*Transaction*TransactionPerson loops which _won't_ be acceptable performance wise, even if I do it more rare (when I add or edit a TransactionPerson). Even if I should cache that data (a list of persons) on the Transaction, that would be the same as what I suggested in my question, but with the addition of having the relationship data in a list as well. It wouldn't lead to duplicated data. How would you do it?

Comment: Summarizing at write time is a good idea, but so is denormalizing, as the OP does in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Yes, you can rely on the order being maintained. From the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html#Property_Classes_and_Types):

> when entities are returned by queries and get(), the list properties values are in the same order as when they were stored. There's one exception to this: Blob and Text values are moved to the end of the list; however, they retain their original order relative to each other.

**2.** Yes, ListProperties are your friends for de-normalizing relationships. I tend to duplicate data a lot, and use list-properties like 'caches' of de-normalized data in this way.

Comment: Regarding (2), what do you mean with duplicating data? In my case it is no duplication, only a way to store the realationship data?

Comment: As in sometimes I will keep a normalised setup, `A has many B` but whenever I save `B's`, I also cache some of the important data in lists on `A` for faster processing later.